# Search into a json file a value with only javascript and fs

Tags: javascript, json, object

i want to create a javascript function for search into a json file a object with the value.

```
getByValue(value) {
//the code            
}
```

When i call the function, i need to search into a json file (the path is "./database/table.json") what i passed with value parameter, and return the object name.

An example:

```
JSON file: 
{"name": "test"}
getByValue(value) {
//code for search into the file           
}

//search on the json file a object value with "test"
console.log(getByValue("test"))
//expected output: "name"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```js
const json = { "name": "test" , "name1" : "test1"}

const getByValue = value => {
  for (let key of Object.keys(json)) if (json[key] === value) return key;
}

//search on the json file a object value with "test"
console.log(getByValue("test"))
//expected output: "name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first load that JSON in JS environment and parse it to read. In `node.js` you can do something like this

```
const jsonFromFile = require('filepath/file.json')
```

After reading the JSON, you just need to find the key where the value is given. There are multiple approaches to this. The basic solution is need to iterate over the object and find the value which matches.
One such approach:

```js
const findKeyBasedOnValue = (obj, value) => Object.keys(obj).find((key) => obj[key] === value)

const data = {a: 'no-test', b: 'test'}

console.log(findKeyBasedOnValue(data, 'test')) // b
```